# Use multiple speakers to play 2 ch audio

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, audio, speakers

My macbook pro has 2 built in speakers and a line-out for audio.

Additionally, I have it connected to my cinema display wich also has 2 speakers.

I want to know how to combine them to use all of them to play my musics so it does't just come from a single output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio MIDI Setup to the rescue!

Open `Audio MIDI Setup` which is located in `Applications > Utilities`.

Click the `+` icon in the bottom-left hand side and choose `Create Multi-Output Device`.

[image: Screenshot of the Left-Hand side of Disk Utility]

When the multi-output device is selected, click the Built-In Output, and the Cinema Display's output audio devices.

After this is done, open `System Preferences` and click the Sound category. Under the `Output` tab, choose the Multi-Output device.

Any applications that were open when you started this process *may* have to be restarted in order to pick up the change in default sound devices. Some do, some don't.

I do believe that should do it.

Comment: The one catch is that you can't adjust the volume of this device (it will be gray on the menu bar). You'll have to Alt+Click on the speaker / volume bar, select one of the sub devices, adjust the volume, repeat for each device, then swap back to the multi device.

Comment: Or use the Sound preference pane, or Audio Midi Setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try [JackAudio](http://jackaudio.org/). It's powerful multi-sources input/output mixer.

Comment: You don't need any external software to accomplish this.